# Which is tougher to learn native Android or flutter?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, flutter, cross-platform, native

I am a college student doing my bachelor's in computer science.

I wanted to learn mobile app development so I learned Native Android development, which took me 6 months to learn, and do some freelancing.

But now I am hearing that Native development is going to die out slowly and cross-platform frameworks are the future,

So I first thought about ionic but was not sure about it cause it doesn't have all the features as native cause it's basically a website running in a `webview`.

But I decided on Flutter cause it's backed by Google, is cross-platform, and runs at almost native speeds and since its Google, good support is expected in the future.

My question is Flutter harder to learn than Native Android ? and since I already know Native does that help me in learning it?

Comment: It's a subjective question and really depends on capabilities of the learner. I can only tell that due to flutter being newer, it'll be harder to learn due to less resources, and you won't get answers quickly if you face any error while development.

Comment: what do you suggest then i should stick with native development or go for other older frameworks like ionic ?

Comment: Opinion questions are off-topic on StackOverflow, see [What Not to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). No one knows what the future holds, and everyone has a different opinion.

Comment: Well it's reeeeaaaaaally opinionated question. As Morrison Chang suggested, nobody knows what future holds. Totally depends if you're willing to risk it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a very open-ended question.

Is Flutter harder to learn than Native Android? Not really, depending on how good your programming foundation is, you can pick up "Dart" pretty quickly as it is very similar to the languages you program a native Android app.

Given that you already know Native Android development, you can learn this on the side or maybe full-time if your schedule permits. Knowing mobile development that you mention is going to come in handy.

No one knows about the future of Flutter since there have been many attempts for doing cross-platform development by various companies of this scale. Also, having researched extensively about Flutter it does seem a bit immature, so for any established product to move forward with Flutter, there has to happen a decent amount of de-risking before you can actually make a decision and move forward with it.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter faces a significant challenge due to a lack of resources, often leading to difficulties in finding answers or solutions for questions/bugs. React Native has a similar issue but to a lesser extent.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).